# I want when i enter string value in form Controller Return value in Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

***This is My Controller***
***Please Tell me How to solve This Issue***
*I want when i enter string value in form Controller Return value in Id but it return in String*

This issue was occur when i can save data in that Technology field

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ProjectId, ProjectName,Description,Start,End,ProjectHead,Status,Technology")] Project project)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(project);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                var tech = project.Technology.Split(",");
                foreach(var te in tech)
                {
                    ProjectTechnology projectTechnology = new ProjectTechnology();
                    projectTechnology.ProjectId = project.ProjectId;
                    projectTechnology.TechnologyId = Convert.ToInt32(te);
                    _context.Add(projectTechnology);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                return RedirectToAction( nameof (Index));
            }
            return View(project);
        }
,,,
```

Comment: Could you please tell us what your `Project` class looks like? Also, when you say ID do you mean `Guid`?

Comment: when i use breakpoint on create and run the project when breakdown redirect to code storage value shown in string